# Antiferromagnetic chain from Altland/Simons book (p.81)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, spin-models, spin-chains

In Condensed Matter Field Theory (2nd edition) by Altland/Simons there considered antiferromagnetic chain with Hamiltonian:
$$H = J\sum_{<n,m>} S_nS_m = J\sum_{<n,m>}[S^{z}_n S^{z}_m + \frac{1}{2}(S^{+}_{n}S^{-}_{m}+S^{-}_{n}S^{+}_{m})]$$
When apply a canonical transformation to the Hamiltonian
in which the spins on one sublattice, say B, are rotated through 180◦ about the x-axis, i.e. $S^{x}_{B}\rightarrow \widetilde{S^{x}_B} = S^{x}_{B};\ \   S^{y}_{B}\rightarrow \widetilde{S^{y}_B} = -S^{y}_{B};\ \  S^{z}_{B}\rightarrow \widetilde{S^{z}_B} = -S^{z}_{B},$. Represented in terms of the transformed operators, the Hamiltonian takes the form:
$$H = -J\sum_{<n,m>}[S^{z}_n \widetilde{S^{z}}_m + \frac{1}{2}(S^{+}_{n}\widetilde{S^{+}_{m}}+S^{-}_{n}\widetilde{S^{-}_{m}})]$$
Applying an expansion of the Holstein–Primakoff representation $S^{-}_{m} \approx (2S)^{1/2}a^+_m$ one obtains the Hamiltonian:
$$H = -NJS^{2}+JS\sum_{m}[2a_{n}a^{+}_{m}+(a_{n}a_{m}+h.c.)] + O(S^{0})$$
I cannot understand how we get terms $a_na_{m} + h.c.$, because we have:
$$\widetilde{S^{+}_{m}} = \widetilde{S^{x}_{m}}+i\widetilde{S^{y}_{m}} = S^{x}_{m} - iS^{y}_{m} = (2S)^{1/2}a^{+}_m$$
so in the Hamiltonian we have to have $a_{n}a^{+}_{m}$. But it seems that $\widetilde{S^{+}_{m}} \approx (2S)^{1/2}a_m$, as if we apply the Holstein–Primakoff representations for $S^{+}_{m}$ and  $\widetilde{S^{+}_{m}}$ independently, and then identify their boson operators.

Answer (score 1):

You want to substitute
$$
S_m^- = (2S)^{1/2} a_m^\dagger
$$
(on the A sublattice) as well as
$$
\tilde S_m^- = (2S)^{1/2} a_m^\dagger
$$
(on the B sublattice).

Then you will obtain the desired results.

Note that since $S$ ($\tilde S$) appears only on the A (B) sublattice, there is a clear meaning what $a_m$ is for each lattice site.

Also note that in the book on pg 81, it says *"Once again, applying an expansion of the Holstein-Primakoff representation, $S_m^- \simeq (2S)^{1/2} a_m^\dagger$, ***etc.***, one obtains"*  (emphasis mine, but note the "etc."!)